# Cannot see backtrace in TestFlight crash report - "No Threads: Compression May Be Hiding Threads"

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

In my TestFlight crash report in Xcode 7, I am not seeing a backtrace. Instead the message displayed in the backtrace area is: "No Threads: Compression May Be Hiding Threads". I am including debug symbols in my TestFlight build. Any idea why the threads are hidden?